# Default search does not show part of a word

Tags: search

I did a search using the following word "Sub", but nothing return back. while if I search for the word "subpage" it will show all the pages containing the word "subpage"? , so how I can define the search to view all the word or sub word occurrence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find results where your search term is only part of the Word you have to add the * wildcard character like "Sub*", but note that it only Works as suffix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is there a way to modify the search service to automatically search for any sub-word.

Comment: You might create your own web part deriving from the core results web part which added the Wildcard, but in my opinion it would be better to teach people how to search as it's a lot more powerful to allow users to specify what they want